# What is the difference between HttpContext.Current.Request AND HttpContext.Current.Response

Tags: asp.net, cookies

When asking a cookie why does it matters in where does it comes from? Request or Response...
isnt:

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(LangKey).Value`
And
`HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Get(LangKey).Value`

Suppose to be the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Request has the current cookie of the client.  Response is used to set the cookie browser side.

Comment: So when I read a cookie I need to use Request and when I write I need to use Response? thanks

Comment: For set cookie you must use Set method of these 2 Items.

Comment: Of course you use set to set! The point is Request holds the client's current cookie and response has the cookie that will be sent with response.